# Simple open/close Form2 with same Button in Form1

Tags: c#, forms

There are many variations of that question, and I probably read them all ;)
But I guess not this particular one.
Of course this can't work like that, because my Form2 object only exists in that "button1_Click"....at least I guess.
Form 2 should be non-modal....but has many methods in it going on....Form1 should still be usable.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private object frm;
        public bool form2IsOpen { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                if (form2IsOpen == false)
                {
                Form2 frm = new Form2();
                frm.Show();
                form2IsOpen = true;
                   }
                else
                {
                    frm.Close();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry prashant..just wanted to edit myself :(  thx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are re-declaring the "frm" variable as a local variable that goes out of scope after the form gets created. This fixes what you were attempting to do in your code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 frm;
    public bool form2IsOpen { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (form2IsOpen == false)
        {
            frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
            form2IsOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frm.Close();
            form2IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the `Form2` object only exists in that method. If you're looking at the form then obviously the object exists. It's that the variable that refers to that object only exists in that method. The obvious solution is to not assign it to a variable that exists only in that method. What sort of variable exists in all methods? A member variable of course. You're already using one for the flag so why not for the form too?

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();    .....like that? it runs the code but not closes Form2...of course I deleted that line now in the button event...so it should be in the scope of Form1..?

Comment: and if form2 is a beast, this way with form2IsOpen, I initialize it only if needed. right?  because of possible complex constructor,...which changes over time, or at least the variables inside it. that would make sense right?

Comment: You don't even need that flag. You can simply set your `Form2` field to null when the form closes, so all you have to do is check whether the field is null or not to know whether a form is open.

Comment: thx for that extra advice...but then I need to put `Form2 frm = new Form2();` on the very top,, and if it got complicated getters, which change over time, I need to put  `Form2 frm = new Form2();` after the check. I am not there yet, but in the end it should work that way. or maybe I am mistaken again..just learning

Comment: No, you don't need to put that at the top.  In fact, you specifically need to NOT put that at the top, since that would mean that the field was not `null` the first time you click the `Button` so it would try to close it.  It's pretty simple stuff. The field is initially `null`, you test whether it's `null` on a click, create and show if it is and close if it's not. Handle the `FormClosed` event of the form and null the field.

Comment: thx for the explanation...I did it so anyway....problem is I already have a huge DB access and Filelist access and combination of those, a clickthrough-Hud to show all, it works pretty nice and shows correctly, but I missed to learn the basics,..like objects and so on. But I start to get a grasp of it...puuh

Answer (score 1):

If all your trying to do is open and close the form with one button, then why not try this

```
private void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(Form2.IsVisible){
    Form2.Hide();
}
else{
    Form2.Show();
}
```

}

This way it opens and closes the form with one button

Comment: so far i checked ivans response first,...but not it doesn' recognize ".Isvisible" and ".Hide"    I guess its my error...

Comment: You might have to change some of your code. But I do this a lot with buttons and labels and such, with forms and controls out of the toolbox. Try changing your code up a little.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is reason, play with `Hide` and `Show`, you don't really need to create `Form`  everytime.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form2.Visible) form2.Hide(); 
    else form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Hari my friend its you again....always helpful eh? thx I got my error...fixed and understood :))